# Не отображается Title в Shell Page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Почему-то не отображается название выбранной вкладки в заголовке. Вот код страницы:

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Fishing.Views"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   x:Class="Fishing.Views.MainDrawerPage"
   FlyoutHeaderBehavior="CollapseOnScroll">

<!-- Styles and Resources -->
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor"
                Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor"
                Value="Violet"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor"
                Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor"
                Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor"
                Value="Yellow"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="ShellItem"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />

    <Style x:Key="ShellStyle"
           TargetType="Element"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor"
                Value="#546DFE" />
    </Style>

</Shell.Resources>

<Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,20">
            <Grid HeightRequest="100">
                <Label Text="HEADER" HorizontalOptions="End" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="14" 
                       VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="Black" Padding="0,10,10,0" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutHeaderTemplate>


<ShellContent Title="ТЕСТ" Style="{StaticResource ShellStyle}" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:Page1}">
    <ShellContent.Icon>
        <FontImageSource
            FontFamily="MaterialIcons"
            Glyph="{DynamicResource News}"
            Size="30"
            Color="Black" />
    </ShellContent.Icon>
</ShellContent>
</Shell>
```

При запуске приложения, не отображается ожидаемый заголовок. Отправляю следующее изображение для лучшего понимания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, я что-то не так сделал. Что необходимо сделать, чтобы отобразить Title выбранной вкладки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Оказывается, этот Title необходимо объявлять непосредственно в самом View, которым будет заполняться Shell Content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Fishing.Views.Page1" 
         Title="ТЕСТ">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```